# The content is being truncated when I use the LinkedIn API to post on my page

Tags: linkedin-api

The content is being truncated when I use the LinkedIn API to post on my page. Please check the given payload and the output. The post link is https://www.linkedin.com/feed/update/urn:li:share:7138127166130581504/.

payload is

```
{
    "author": "urn:li:organization:99061641",
    "commentary": " Key takeaways from the recent webinar on Challenging Artistic Canons! \n\n *  Artistic greatness has no definitive canon, it's subjective and open to debate. \n *  Lists of the greatest movies or works of art are meant to spark passionate discussions and challenge conventional wisdom. \n *  Use the information as a handy reference guide and challenge your own personal canons. \n *  Push boundaries, think outside the box, and embrace diverse perspectives for artistic growth. \n\n \n\n \n\n( Let's continue to challenge the norms and redefine greatness in art! )\n\n \n\n \n\n#ArtisticGreatness #ChallengingCanons #DebateAndInspire #ThinkOutsideTheBox #ArtisticGrowth #DiversePerspectives",
    "visibility": "PUBLIC",
    "distribution": {
        "feedDistribution": "MAIN_FEED",
        "targetEntities": [],
        "thirdPartyDistributionChannels": []
    },
    "lifecycleState": "PUBLISHED"
}
```

I observed that if there are parentheses () within the text, an issue occurs where the entire text doesn't get published. All the text should be published.